# WCF - How to bypass server certificate validation in web.config

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, ssl

I am very new to the development of web services in general and I have a question.
Is there a way to configure the web.config file so that my web service can accept whatever endpoint certificates?

The point is that my webservice points to another web service that is listening on port 4799 over https and the error that I am now getting is:

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could
> not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with
> authority 'localhost:4799'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The
> underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
> relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. --->
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
> certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <system.web>      
      <identity impersonate="true" userName="COSMO\adminqlik2" password="Ql1kAdmin!" />      
      <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
  
  <system.serviceModel>
      <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
          <add name="serviceKeyBehavior" type="EDXWrapper.ServiceKeyBehaviorExtensionElement, EDXWrapper, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        </behaviorExtensions>
      </extensions>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="ServiceKeyEndpointBehavior">
                <serviceKeyBehavior />
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>

      <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IQMS">
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IQTService">
                    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WsSecured">
                <security mode="Transport">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="None"
                             negotiateServiceCredential="false"
                             establishSecurityContext="false" />
                    </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://localhost:4799/QMS/Service" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsSecured" contract="QmsAPI.IQMS" name="WsSecured_IQMS" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceKeyEndpointBehavior" />
            <endpoint address="https://localhost:4799/ANY/Service" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsSecured" contract="QmsAPI.IQTService" name="WsSecured    _IQTService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceKeyEndpointBehavior" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"></httpErrors>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What should I do?